# Зачем нужны dll wxWidgets с сайта производителя?

Tags: wxwidgets

На сайте wxWidgets предлагается скачать не только исходники, которые потом надо собирать у себя на компьютере, но и готовые собранные библиотеки. Я предположил, что такой способ установки библиотеки будет проще, чем сборка вручную, и попробовал создать папку и в неё распаковать include и lib - не пашет. CodeBlocks при создании проекта при любой комбинации галок "монолитно" "dll" и "Unicode" пишет, что не найдена подходящая конфигурация для билда. Иду на сайт в поисках документации, но вся документация о том, как программировать под wxWidgets, когда она уже работает, и никаких инструкций, что ещё надо сделать, чтобы она заработала. Более того, даже инструкции по сборке обычно находятся не на их сайте, а где-то ещё. Какой вообще смысл в этих бинарных файлах, если интуитивно понятным способом они не работают, а инструкции по их использованию разработчик не предоставил?

Comment: *"интуитивно понятным способом они не работают"* - добро пожаловать в мир С++ библиотек. А что касается dll c сайта - то они предназначены для конкретных компиляторов, которые надо выбрать при скачивании.

Comment: Любой софт имеет права не работать интуитивно понятным способом при условии наличия внятной инструкции. Её пилят уже почти 30 лет и до сих пор не удосужились по-человечески задокументировать? Или я неправ, и инструкция есть? В таком случае, в качестве ответа на этот вопрос меня устроит ссылка на ОФИЦИАЛЬНУЮ инструкцию. Впрочем, многие статьи на cppreference ещё и грешат невнятностью изложения, но они хотя бы есть. Но для изучения незнакомых тем они не подходят, их только как справочник можно использовать, когда в целом тему знаешь.

Comment: "не пашет" - это не проблема. Если у вас возникли сложности то опишите конкретно, какой у вас компилятор, какая система сборки,какие команды  используются при сборке, если сборка не проходит, то приведите лог сборки. wxWidgets куда лучше поддерживается чем многие другие библиотеки.

Comment: Ларчик открывался просто: оказывается, в папке lib надо было переименовать папку gcc720_dll в gcc_dll. И некоторые из предлагаемых библиотек в программу не включать. Только где в официальной инструкции написано, что надо так сделать? Я догадался попробовать это лишь потому, что если компилировать библиотеки у себя на компе, все dll и .a к ним создаются в папке с таким именем. А что делать разработчику, который не хочет заморачиваться с работой в Gentoo-style и столкнулся с этой проблемой?